# group by but still displaying all data?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i wonder how to using group by but still displaying full data? i just want to group it.

here i give an example of my table :

[image: picture]

this is my query :

```
(SELECT dp.menu_paket,d.id_detail,t.no_meja,m.nama_menu,d.jumlah,t.status,t.nama_pegawai
FROM menu m
join detail_paket dp on dp.menu_paket=m.nama_menu
JOIN detail_transaksi d on m.id_menu = d.id_menu
join transaksi t on t.id_transaksi=d.id_transaksi where t.status='progress' and d.status_menu='progress' group by id_detail) 
UNION
(SELECT dp.menu_paket,d.id_detail,t.no_meja,p.nama_paket,d.jumlah,t.status,t.nama_pegawai
FROM paket p
join detail_paket dp on dp.id_paket=p.id_paket
JOIN detail_transaksi d on d.id_paket=p.id_paket
join transaksi t on t.id_transaksi=d.id_transaksi where t.status='progress' and d.status_menu='progress' group by id_detail);
```

thanks..!

Comment: Why do you say those 2 rows should disappear? what is the logic?

Comment: It would be a very good idea to indicate what database you're using. SQL Server? PostgreSQL? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: @jpmc26 database is mysql.

Comment: @galuano1 yes, those 2 rows should be appear not disapear, i want to group it but those 2 rows still appear not disapear.

Comment: and why should they be grouped together?

Comment: @galuano1 because its list of MENU which is made by the kitchen.actualy what i want is order by id_detail and group by id_transaksi, but now im using those query and its not working.if you see the right table, the No Meja column should be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply distinct to avoid same multiple records instead of group by. because group by is used when there is aggregate function is your query.
Distinct retrieves single row instead of multiple rows when two rows are totally same.

Try this

```
select distinct columnname from table name
union
select distinct columnname1 from table name
```

Comment: You don't need the `distinct` if you use `UNION`, because the `UNION` operator will removed duplicates automatically.

Comment: I'm confused. I didn't see any indication the poster wants to remove duplicate rows. Everything I see suggests he/she just wants to control ordering.

Answer (score -1):

I think I see two issues.

1) `GROUP BY` is generally used when you want to group rows for an aggregate function like `SUM`. You may be looking for `ORDER BY`, which controls the order of the rows. You can specify multiple columns for `ORDER BY` to obtain a "grouping" effect. This is what you want if you just want the rows to be next to each other in the list.

2) `UNION`, at least in the databases I know of, removes duplicate rows. You want `UNION ALL` if you want to preserve all rows.

**Edit:**

In response to the poster's comment, you definitely want `ORDER BY` and maybe `UNION ALL`. It should be `ORDER BY no_meja, id_transaksi`. Try the following query and see if it gives you what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT dp.menu_paket,d.id_detail,t.no_meja,m.nama_menu,d.jumlah,t.status,t.nama_pegawai
FROM menu m
join detail_paket dp on dp.menu_paket=m.nama_menu
JOIN detail_transaksi d on m.id_menu = d.id_menu
join transaksi t on t.id_transaksi=d.id_transaksi
where t.status='progress' and d.status_menu='progress') 
UNION ALL
(SELECT dp.menu_paket,d.id_detail,t.no_meja,p.nama_paket,d.jumlah,t.status,t.nama_pegawai
FROM paket p
join detail_paket dp on dp.id_paket=p.id_paket
JOIN detail_transaksi d on d.id_paket=p.id_paket
join transaksi t on t.id_transaksi=d.id_transaksi
where t.status='progress' and d.status_menu='progress')) x
ORDER BY x.no_meja, x.id_transaksi;
```

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? @galuano1 I'm saying remove the `GROUP BY` and add an `ORDER BY` on the `UNION`ed query (and make sure you're using the columns you want to order by); it doesn't look like you need `GROUP BY` at all because you have no aggregates. Truthfully, I would expect these queries to throw errors. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html), which states that "a query that includes a `GROUP BY` clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the `GROUP BY` clause". Change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.